# Gauss-Markov theorem: BLUE and OLS

Tags: regression, least-squares, mse, blue

I'm reading up on the Guass-Markov theorem on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem), and I was hoping somebody could help me figure out the main point of the theorem.

We assume a linear model, in matrix form, is given by:
$$ y = X\beta +\eta $$
and we're looking for the BLUE, $ \widehat\beta $.

In accordance with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals_in_statistics), I would label $\eta = y - X\beta$ the "residual" and 
$\varepsilon = \widehat\beta - \beta$ the "error". (I.e the opposite of the usage on the Gauss-Markov page).

The OLS (ordinary least-squares) estimator may be derived as the argmin of $||\text{residual}||_2^2 = ||\eta||_2^2$.

Now, let $\mathbb{E}$ denote the expectation operator. To my understanding, what the Gauss-Markov theorem tells us is that, if $\mathbb{E}(\eta) = 0$ and $\text{Var}(\eta) = \sigma^2 I $, then  the argmin, over all linear, unbiased estimators, of $\mathbb{E}(||\text{error}||_2^2) = \mathbb{E} (||\varepsilon||_2^2)$ is given by the same expression as the OLS estimator.

I.e. 
$$ \text{argmin}_{\text{} \widehat\beta(y)} \, ||\eta||_2^2 
\;=\; (X'X)^{-1}X'y \;=\;
\text{argmin}_{\text{linear, unbiased } \widehat\beta(y)} \, \mathbb{E}(||\varepsilon||_2^2)$$

Is my understanding correct? And if so, would you say that it deserves more prominent emphasis in the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my hunch was correct indeed, as confirmed, e.g. on page 375 of the book
[Introductory Econometrics](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-7oM9FYZfkkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Introductory%20Econometrics:%20Using%20Monte%20Carlo%20Simulation%20with%20Microsoft%20Excel&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qZC4UZyeLaiE4gTQvIDIAw&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAA). Relevant excerpt:

[image: Excerpt from book]

Comment: Please write something more since your answer could be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 15):

I am not sure if I understood you question correctly, but if you are looking to prove that the OLS for $\hat{\beta}$ is BLUE (best linear unbiased estimator) you have to prove the following two things: First that $\hat{\beta}$ is unbiased and second that $Var(\hat{\beta})$ is the smallest among all linear unbiased estimators.

Proof that OLS estimator is unbiased can be found here http://economictheoryblog.com/2015/02/19/ols_estimator/

and proof that $Var(\hat{\beta})$ is the smallest among all linear unbiased estimators can be found here http://economictheoryblog.com/2015/02/26/markov_theorem/

Comment: Proofs are helpful, yes.